# I am using React Type animation and i want to add css to multilineText in sequence

Tags: reactjs, animation, react-typescript

my code is

```
<TypeAnimation    
    sequence={[
      `Connecting to global server... Connected\nPerforming User Authentication... <span  style="color: green>Done</span> \nPerforming User Authentication... Done\nEncrypting server: 256bit_Packet_Encryption... Done\nRetrieving current server script: read_source_server_source... Done\nConnect to database... Done\nAttempt (1) to bypass the security System... Buffering\nAttempt (2) to bypass the security System... Done\nSending Requested WINRATE to Your Account... Done\nSending Requested JACKPOT and WINRATE to Your Account... Done\nChanging packets in the database... Done\nConnecting to All slots Server... Done\nConnecting to All slots database... Done\nGenerate WINRATE and JACKPOT... Done\nProcess was completed successfully.\n`,
       
    ]}
    wrapper='span'
    speed={75}
    // repeat={false}
    style={{
      whiteSpace: "pre-line",
      fontSize: "10px",
      color: "#368DE0",
    }}
    repeat={0}
    cursor={false}
 
/>
```

in this multiline sequence I want status like Done Buffering in difference colors with delay but in this css can be apply to whole text not single text in between because sequence is string so they treat it like string so how can i do this type of animation can anyone help me out with it.

[I want to display like this using type animation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QsLgm.png)